# Why is linq executing the same code twice depending on where I put ToList?

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

When I call the following function:

```
public ICombatTransaction PayCost(CostTransaction costTransaction)
{
    if (costTransaction.Cost is CompositeAndCost compositeAndCost)
    {
        var res = compositeAndCost.Costs.Select(cost => PayCost(new CostTransaction(costTransaction.Source, cost, costTransaction, this)));

        if (res.All(t => t.IsFulfilled))
            return new CompositeFulfilledTransaction(res.ToList(), costTransaction, this);

        throw new Exception($"Composite 'and' system cannot pay ({string.Join(", ", res.Where(x => !x.IsFulfilled).Select(x => ((CostTransaction)x).Cost.GetType()))}) costs");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var costSystem in CostSystems)
            if (costSystem.Accepts(costTransaction.Cost.GetType()))
                return costSystem.PayCost(costTransaction);

        return costTransaction;
    }
}
```

The recursive `PayCost` call in line 5 ends up getting called **twice** for each element in
`compositeAndCost.Costs`. This is not intentional. Simply moving the `ToList` from under the if statement to above it resolves this problem entirely:

```
public ICombatTransaction PayCost(CostTransaction costTransaction)
{
    if (costTransaction.Cost is CompositeAndCost compositeAndCost)
    {
        var res = compositeAndCost.Costs.Select(cost => PayCost(new CostTransaction(costTransaction.Source, cost, costTransaction, this))).ToList();

        if (res.All(t => t.IsFulfilled))
            return new CompositeFulfilledTransaction(res, costTransaction, this);

        throw new Exception($"Composite 'and' system cannot pay ({string.Join(", ", res.Where(x => !x.IsFulfilled).Select(x => ((CostTransaction)x).Cost.GetType()))}) costs");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var costSystem in CostSystems)
            if (costSystem.Accepts(costTransaction.Cost.GetType()))
                return costSystem.PayCost(costTransaction);

        return costTransaction;
    }
}
```

This is one of the strangest C# bugs I've ever seen, I haven't seen anything like it in like 7 years of working with C# and Linq. I'm sure it's because of lazy evaluation (which I didn't know C# just did sometimes!) but I still don't understand the mechanism that leads to calling a function twice, and I don't understand why it isn't resolving to a list when `res.All` is called.

My concrete questions are 1. what's the exact mechanism that leads to calling the function twice and 2. what should I be thinking about/paying attention to in order to avoid this kind of bug when using linq?

Comment: If you have used ADO.NET before, you can think of a LINQ query as being like a `SqlCommand` object. It contains the instructions to get data but it doesn't contain the data itself. Just like you will be executing the query and retrieving data each time you use a `SqlCommand` object, so you will be executing a query and retrieving data when you use a LINQ query. In both cases, you're generally going to want to execute the query once to get the results, then use those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.
LinQ select return IEnumerable. It means, that it's not loading data until you need to access it.
For example if you have database 'MyDbContext' with table 'Data'.
Then in some method you use it:

```
var records = MyDbContext.Data.Select(o=>o.Id>10); // this not loading data to records
var count = records.Count(); // here all query data is loaded from DB and returns count.
var secondCount = records.Count() // here again data is loaded from DB and returns count.
```

but if you change first line to:

```
var records = MyDbContext.Data.Select(o=>o.Id>10).ToList();
```

then data from database would be loaded once. Because ToList() creates an object with data.
So when you need to make several manipulations with same data, like counting, sorting and etc. it is better to load it to list or array.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if C# just switched to a list the first time he data has to be loaded? Why do it again every time if it's the same? When the first count is called why wouldn't records be replaced with a list or anything concrete instead of the lazily loaded statement (since records is ienumerable a list can fit in its datatype).

Comment: It's different concept. IEnumerable gives you enumeration over object. So you just get data without ability to modify it. You're sure, that data is not changing. When using list you have all control and here you can add new elements change values and etc. It's different techniques. Here is good explanation of it: https://benbrougher.tech/posts/why-use-ienumerable/